# "'NoneType' object is not iterable" when the code works fine for others. How do I figure out what's wrong?

Tags: python, loops, typeerror, nonetype

I'm following a guided project in Python and there's code I wrote that seems to align with the solution, however, I'm getting an error while they did not.

I saw online that a return statement might be needed but the solution doesn't use one and no matter where I place the return, I get an error anyway.

`"displayfreq"` is a code I defined above in the code; it produces a sorted frequency table.

```
genres_ios = displayfreq(ios_free, -5)

for genre in genres_ios:
    total = 0
    len_genre = 0

    for app in ios_free:
        genre_app = app[-5]
        if genre_app == genre:
            tot_ratings = float(app[5])
            total += tot_ratings
            len_genre += 1
    avg_tot_rating = total / len_genre
    print(genre, 'with average total rating of', avg_tot_ratings)
```

I expected to see the average number of ratings per genre, but instead, I'm getting,

> "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

for the line `"for genre in genres_ios"`

Comment: `How do I figure out what's wrong?` Figure out why `displayfreq` is returning `None`

Comment: It means the value returns from `displayfreq(ios_free, -5)` is `None` (which you can't iterate through)

Answer (score 0):

A return statement *is* needed in `displayfreq()`, or it will return `None`. Because `genres_ios` is `None`, you cannot iterate over it and you get the error.

If it works on other machines, `displayfreq()` might not work for your machine.

Comment: I'm new to Python, can `print()` be used in place of `return`? `displayfreq()` works just fine in code that I've done above.

Comment: `print()` is very different from `return`. The former outputs text to the terminal while the latter is what a function equals when called.

Answer (score 0):

As you specified that you are getting *"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"* for the line "*for genre in genres_ios:*...", it means that the variable *genres_ios* is having value *None* and thus you are getting such an error.

For this, you need to **return** the variable or expression of your sorted frequency table.

Also note that in the function displayfreq, you are not manipulating the ios_free variable or you would have the value of ios_free changed. If you want a copy of ios_free use **ios_free.copy()**.